# Querying Managed package version from Apex

Tags: managed-package

Is it possible to query the version number of an installed managed package? I do not find any information in the PackageLicense object. If not, what is the alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sfdcfox mentioned, finding the version number using Metadata API was not anywhere close to trivial:), got some code finally running after many attempts, posting the code here :
Download MetadataService class from [https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/tree/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes]

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();

service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();

service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

System.debug('sessionId'+service.SessionHeader.sessionId);

List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();        

MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryLayout = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();

queryLayout.type_x = 'InstalledPackage';
queries.add(queryLayout);       

MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties1 = service.listMetadata(queries, 34);

List<String> packageNames = new List<String>(); 
for (MetadataService.FileProperties n : fileProperties1) {

   if(n.fullName=='ts2')
    packageNames.add(n.fullName);
}

List<MetadataService.InstalledPackage> installPackageInfo = 
    (List<MetadataService.InstalledPackage>) 
    service.readMetadata('InstalledPackage', packageNames).getRecords();

for(MetadataService.InstalledPackage a:installPackageInfo)
{

  System.debug(a.fullName +'*****'+a.versionNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From within managed code, you can use the [Version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_version.htm) interface to determine the current version. It involves making use of System.requestVersion() to get the current version that's running, and provides an example of how to use it, included here:

```
if (System.requestVersion() == new Version(1,0))
{
// Do something
}
if ((System.requestVersion().major() == 1)
     && (System.requestVersion().minor() > 0)
     && (System.requestVersion().minor() <=9))
{
    // Do something different for versions 1.1 to 1.9
}
else if (System.requestVersion().compareTo(new Version(2,0)) >= 0)
{
    // Do something completely different for versions 2.0 or greater
}
```

Outside of managed code, you'd have to use the Metadata API to get the installed version. This would be non-trivial, but is possible. The [Apex Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) might be of some use to you.