# ProcedureException not being caught

Tags: apex, managed-package, exception

I'm checking the current version of a managed package and for that I'm using the `System.requestVersion()` method. The documentation states that this method only works for orgs with managed packages:

> The requestVersion method isn’t supported for unmanaged packages. If you call it from an unmanaged package, an exception will be thrown.

I was actually counting on that and in my code I wrote this:

```
Boolean appAccessEnabled = false;
try {
    appAccessEnabled = System.requestVersion().compareTo(new Version(2,22)) >= 0;
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Handle exception
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

But for some reason I keep getting this on my log after running the method:

```
12:48:37:011 FATAL_ERROR System.ProcedureException: Method is not supported from an unmanaged namespace
```

I first tried to catch the `ProcedureException` but that didn't work so I tried to catch a general `Exception` but that gave me the same result.

Any idea on how can I handle this?

My main goal is to check the current version of a managed package, but even if the package doesn't exist in the org I need to be able to tell.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you want [the solution here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82143/querying-managed-package-version-from-apex) using the metadata API