# From inside a Salesforce packaging org, how do you query the list of created versions for a managed package?

Tags: apex, api, managed-package, dml, versioning

I have, a Salesforce packaging org, it contains a managed package with a namespace.

I **need** to be able to query the list of created versions for that managed package.

I am aware that a user can go to the package and click on versions, and manually see them.  I need to know how to do this programmatically. Either via APEX/DML/SOQL/SOSL/API/other.

The use case: I have an automated deployment pipeline that gets initiated by a user, they specify the version of the package they intend to build in a SEPARATE org. I need to verify the version they have entered does not already exist prior to starting the automation.

----- EDIT ------

I see someone linked a previous post about getting the version of the installed managed packages, I am not looking for installed managed packages (a package installed from somewhere other than me, like the app exchange). I'm looking for the versions of packages (code) that I maintain and distribute to others as installed managed packages. Unless there is something I'm missing the other link does not solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying Managed package version from Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82143/querying-managed-package-version-from-apex)

Comment: I don't think so, the issue there looks like they are trying to get the version of an installed package, not a list of package versions they manage, unless I'm miss understanding the other post. @battery.cord

Comment: Thanks for adding some additional clarifications- I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [MetadataPackageVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatapackageversion.htm) (keyprefix [04t](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#04t)) in the Tooling API.

> Represents a package version (managed or unmanaged) that has been uploaded from the org you’re logged in to. Available in Tooling API version 38.0 and later.

You might also need the parent [MetadataPackage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatapackage.htm).

> Represents a managed or unmanaged package that has been developed in the org you’re logged in to. Available in Tooling API version 38.0 and later.