# Email Alert When Package Installed In Your Org

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package, email-alert

When you install a package, the person who installed it gets the email from Salesforce -
*Your request to install package "Package Name" was successful.*

I would like to replicate this, but send it to all System Admins - a)would be nice to know and b)good practice as I learn my way around Apex.

The goal:

```
// 1 - "Trigger" on Package install
// 2 - Use some package info (Id, Name, Prefix, Version, etc...) 
// 3 - Get list of Users with System Admin profile 
// 4 - Send SysAdmin list an email notification
```

3 & 4 are fine, but I can't figure out 1 & 2.

[I saw this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218761/querying-installed-managed-package-version-numbers-from-apex-in-2018?newreg=e92bd9e184ea457783726217be516ddb) about InstalledSubscriberPackage using tooling API and some Salesforce documentation like [Package Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_package.htm).
Any thoughts or documentation that will point me in the right direction?
While the different API stuff is a little above my current skill set, the concept seems do-able, just haven't been able to connect the dots.

Thanks for any help/advice!

Comment: See the InstallHandler interface, see the link have example of sending email https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_post_install_script_create.htm

Comment: Great, thanks so much @LironC.